# Combining the ::slotted and ::part pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, custom-element

I'm trying to use the `::slotted` selector in combination with the `::part` selector, I want an outer custom element to style a part in an inner custom element, the problem is that I can't get it to work.

So my question is, is my syntax wrong? Is this not possible to do?

Here is a basic example demonstration, I want the parent element to make the button in the child element have a red background

```js
class ParentElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        let template = document.querySelector("template#parent-template");
        this.shadowRoot.append(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

customElements.define("parent-element", ParentElement);


class ChildElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        let template = document.querySelector("template#child-template");
        this.shadowRoot.append(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

customElements.define("child-element", ChildElement);
```

```html
<template id="parent-template">
    <style>
        :host {
            background-color: pink;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        ::slotted(child-element) {
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        ::slotted(child-element)::part(button) {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <slot></slot>
</template>

<template id="child-template">
    <button part="button">Style me!</button>
</template>

<parent-element>
    <child-element></child-element>
</parent-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this right now, but that feature is currently being reviewed for addition to the spec. See https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3896 and https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7922

Answer (score 0):

You could define the style in the `parent-element`:

```js
class ParentElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        let template = document.querySelector("template#parent-template");
        this.shadowRoot.append(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

customElements.define("parent-element", ParentElement);


class ChildElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        let template = document.querySelector("template#child-template");
        this.shadowRoot.append(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

customElements.define("child-element", ChildElement);
```

```html
<template id="parent-template">
    <style>
        :host {
            background-color: pink;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        ::slotted(child-element) {
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <slot></slot>
</template>

<template id="child-template">
    <button part="button">Style me!</button>
</template>

<parent-element>
    <style>
        child-element::part(button) {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <child-element></child-element>
</parent-element>
```

or directly in the `child-element`:

```js
class ParentElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        let template = document.querySelector("template#parent-template");
        this.shadowRoot.append(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

customElements.define("parent-element", ParentElement);


class ChildElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        let template = document.querySelector("template#child-template");
        this.shadowRoot.append(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

customElements.define("child-element", ChildElement);
```

```html
<template id="parent-template">
    <style>
        :host {
            background-color: pink;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        ::slotted(child-element) {
            background-color: blue;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <slot></slot>
</template>

<template id="child-template">
    <style>
        button {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <button part="button">Style me!</button>
</template>

<parent-element>
    <child-element></child-element>
</parent-element>
```

Comment: @Mendy you edited two times my answer. Did you test it? Please give a feedback...

Comment: I edited it but I then realized that I didn't understand it correctly so I rolled it back to the original answer

Comment: I'm afraid that this won't resolve it, requiring every consumer of `parent-element` to add styles is not optimal to say the least, however this answer might still be useful for some users stumbling upon this page. Thanks a lot @biberman for the effort you put in to help I really appreciate it even though I won't be able to use this